# How can I access the property `data` in this type?

Tags: typescript, ng-apexcharts

I have this type which comes from a lib:

```
export interface AllChartOptions {
  series: ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries;
  ...
}
```

And here is the type of `series`

```js
export declare type ApexAxisChartSeries = {
    name?: string;
    type?: string;
    color?: string;
    group?: string;
    data: (number | null)[] | {
        x: any;
        y: any;
        ...
    }[] | [number, number | null][] | [number, (number | null)[]][] | number[][];
}[];
export declare type ApexNonAxisChartSeries = number[];
```

From what I understand, with `series` being of type `ApexAxisChartSeries`, it has the property `data`. So I should be able to do

```js
chart.series.map((singleSeries)=> {...})
```

And I should be able to access `data` from singleSeries, right? Vscode tells me that singleSeries is of type:

```js
singleSeries: number | {
  name?: string | undefined;
  type?: string | undefined;
  color?: string | undefined;
  group?: string | undefined;
  data: number[][] | (number | null)[] | {
      x: any;
      y: any;
      fill?: ApexFill | undefined;
      ... 5 more ...;
      columnWidthOffset?: number | undefined;
  }[] | [...][] | [...][];
}
```

but the only options available to me to interact with `singleSeries` are `toLocaleString, toString, valueOf`. What's going on? How can I access `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since series is of type `ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries`, it could also be a `number[]`. So I think it should work if you exclude that it's not of type `number[]`

Something like this might work

```js
chart.series.map((singleSeries)=> {
  // With this row Typescript can know that it's of type ApexAxisChartSeries inside the if statement.
  if("data" in singleSeries) {
    singleSeries.data
  }
})
```

**OR**, if you know that it's not necessary to check this, because you're in control of the data, you can assert.

```js
chart.series.map((singleSeries)=> {
  const singleAxisSeries = singleSeries as ApexAxisChartSeries;
  singleAxisSeries.data:
})
```

Comment: Now the autocomplete recognizes all properties of data, but it still gives me an error:   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'object'.

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error?

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier @Felix Eklöf. I tried to implement your idea incorrectly. It did work after all, thank you!